# Scheduled Trigger flow not worked with Pause element

Tags: visual-flows, scheduled, flow-screen-component

I need the clarification on creating a flow for the below scenario.

I hope this flow needs to create with "Pause" element. That's the reason I tried with Scheduled triggered flow. But am not aware where I did the wrong and why its not triggering properly. please anyone guide on this.

Scenario :

Object : Case

Fields :

Status - > New, Pending, Escalated, Working for Review

The Scenario was,

1. If the Case status is New and the duration of that New status was 2 hours means --> A email alert should sent to Case owner 1
2. If the Case status is Pending  and the duration of that Pending status was 3 hours means --> A email alert should sent to Case owner 2
3. If the Case status is Escalated and the duration of that Escalated status was 4 hours means --> A email alert should sent to Case owner 3.
4. If the Case status is Working for Review  and the duration of that Working for Review status was 4 days means --> A email alert should sent to Case owner 4.

Note : Duration means --> Its the time calculation of status update and we don't having the duration field on case object ( For example : The New status updated on 2 hours before from the current timing)

[image]
Any one please guide me to complete this flow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the normal way this would be done is via `Record-triggered flows with scheduled paths`, not with `Pause` element.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use [Escalation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rules_escalation_create.htm&type=5)?

Comment: @sfdcfox - even better, I always forget about these